# SCALA: How I can initiate another future call within callback from future

Tags: scala

My scenario is, I have multiple API's call to be made and each of them will require to use data from previous call.

Now let's suppose I made a API call with future, and return response of the first call, I am not able to call next API from within Oncomplete of first call.

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can link Futures with flatMap function

```
def firstApiCall(): Future[FirstRes]

def secondApiCall(firstRes: FirstRes): Future[SecondRes]

def combinedCall()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[SecondRes] = firstApiCall.flatMap(res => secondApiCall(res))
```

Comment: this answers my question, but one more thing can I use same function call to process API, with firstApiCALL and secondAPICall?

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question, but you can combine as many flatMap calls as you like, if this answers it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `flatMap` or the cleaner alternative to sequencing a bunch of of futures, which is to use the `for yield` syntax. It's just compile time sugar that will internally transform itself into `flatMap` and `map` and `withFilter` method calls, but it's generally cleaner and easier to read.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

for {
  first <- firstApiCall()
  second <- secondApiCall(first)
} yield second
```